# Change label in webpage via jscriptexecutor of Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have an AUT a web application which is in Japanese. We are trying to follow below approach (not sure if it is correct) to get the Japanese label text into English.

**Approach (using Selenium):**

- Open webpage.
- Get labels as we crawl webpage.
- Send each label to    an API (Japanese dictionary) to get it
  translated in   English.
- Set    back the translated English word to label using java script
  executor.

I have managed to get translated English word for the same japanese label. however , I am stuck for setting it back on webpage. 
Below is the piece of code in selenium that tries to achieve the same.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('expiry').textContent='Expiration Date';}");
```

Here , there are no error messages in eclipse console but same time I am not able to see the English text.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="imui-form" style="width:1050px;">
<div class="imui-chapter-title" style="width:1050px;">
<h2>取引先情報</h2>
</div>
<tr>
<th style="width:80px;" >
<label id="expiry">有効期限</label>
</th>
<td style="width:220px;">
<input type="text" placeholder="" value="2016/08/09"  name="fromdate" id="fromdate" maxlength="" style="width:100px; height:15px;">
<img src="./imart/images/calendar_btn.png" />

&nbsp;～&nbsp;
<input type="text" placeholder="" value=""  name="todate" id="todate" maxlength="" style="width:100px; height:15px;">
<img src="./imart/images/calendar_btn.png" />
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

With this, I have 2 queries:

1. Can anyone guide me if my approach is worth a try or if there is any
   better approach.
2. How should I make above java script work via selenium.

Comment: try using : `js.executeScript("document.getElementById('expiry').innerText='Expiration Date';}");`

Comment: There is no opening curly bracket in your function

Comment: Why are you setting window.onload instead of setting the label directly? If the window has already been loaded, will the set onload even execute? I'd assume not. Also, why is a test even replacing labels on the page?

Comment: @kaqqao : Yes onload event will not work here. I agree. This is not test I am executing. It is just I am trying to get all data into english for tester who will test it. Our application (unfortunately) do not have any localization support as part of architecture.

Comment: @MKay have you tried : `js.executeScript("document.getElementById('expiry').innerTex‌​t='Expiration Date'");`

Comment: @kushal.Yes that was my initial way to do it. However , I received an exception unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using below:

```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.imui-form tr:nth-child(1)>th>label#expiry"));

   JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText='Expiration Date'", element);
```

Comment: you want all that arraylist to be displayed against single element?

Comment: No. Let me edit above script `JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
       js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText="+en.get(i), element);` If I follow this code , I receive a webdriver exception saying  _customer not defined_. Where customer is 0th element in _en list_.

Comment: @MKay try this : `JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver); js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText='"+en.get(i)+"'", element);`